# Ionic V4 ion-back-button changes tabs

Tags: ionic-framework, angular6, ionic4

I have a tab page with 3 differents page. In the second tab, you can push another page. But when you want to come back to the tab page thanks to the ion-back-button, you come back to the first tab instead of the second.

```
ionic (Ionic CLI)          : 4.1.2  (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
Ionic Framework            : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-beta.8
@angular-devkit/core       : 0.7.5
@angular-devkit/schematics : 0.7.5
@angular/cli               : 6.1.5
@ionic/ng-toolkit          : 1.0.8
@ionic/schematics-angular  : 1.0.6
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: That sounds like a bug in Ionic... Have you checked the **[list of issues](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues)** to see if it was already reported by someone else?

Comment: I checked, no one reported it, I reported it [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15494) if anyone is interested in

Answer (score 0):

this is a moment fix while ionic is working on that bug.

html

```
<ion-buttons slot="start">
  <ion-back-button (click)="back()"></ion-back-button>
</ion-buttons>
```

controller

```
back() {
    this.router.navigate(['tabs/tab2']);
  }
```